# Apart from Arabic, is there such a thing as "Islamic languages"?

Tags: language

Is there such a thing as "Islamic languages"?

There's a totally false [online rumour](http://www.truthorfiction.com/rumors/j/Japan-Muslim.htm), spread by people opposed to Islam, claiming that Japan is really anti-Islam. But there's one part that states that "Islamic languages" aren't taught in Japan, and I want to know if there's even such a thing as "Islamic languages".

The exact quote of the rumour is "In the University of Japan, Arabic or any Islamic language is not taught." - it's probably written by someone who isn't a native speaker of English, and it probably means "neither Arabic nor any other Islamic language is taught".

I know that Arabic plays a special role in Islam. For example it's the language the Quran is written in. But are there any other "Islamic languages"?

Comment: Interesting question. / Briefly, I reckon Farsi(Persian) and Urdu. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.** There are no other languages that have links to Islam itself. This can be seen easily by doing a Google search for "Islamic languages". They're probably just trying to make a point and doing it badly. In fact, I can disprove it right [here](http://www.iuj.ac.jp/gsir/iris/syllabus/ircourse.cfm?Category=ALL). That link shows that the University of Japan in fact offers three courses on Arabic.

Answer (score 1):

On the whole, according to the evidences, it is not easy to name another language which could be considered as the second language of the Islam. But we name some other languages which relatively are near to Arabic to some extent. Such as Farsi, Urdu and so on. 
For instance, I found some words which have used in Quran and according to the source have Farsi(Persian) source. e.g.

The word Ebriq (الابریق) has inferred from Aabriz (آبریز)as an old word.
The word Ferdos (فردوس) has inferred from puiridaezu as an Farsi (Avestaian Farsi)
Artor-Jefry as an Colombian linguistic and a scholar of Islam attempt to find the words which came in Arabic (in Quran), his book “The Foreign Vocabulary of the Qur'an”… or even Dr.AzartashAzarnoosh tried to survey the Persian words which have come in Arabic(in Quran)… as a result, we see that there could be some words in Quran which are related to Arabic.

Consequently as I termed, we can some other similar languages which are near and related to Quran more than other language such as Urdu, Farsi(Persian) and so on.

---

**Reference**:

- http://www.aryaadib.blogfa.com/post-233.aspx